# Fading in a Javascript Object after a certain Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have particle object in JavaScript which is called after a certain Time simply like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  particle();
}, 3000);
```

Now I want this object to be faded in slowly to the canvas after the 3 seconds but I don't know how. I have tried using the jQuery `fadeIn()` function but it did nothing to the object.

**EDIT**: I am using the library *particles.js* from  https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/ if you want to see the whole logic behind `particle();`. You can find a working code snippet there. I have not changed the code by a lot except for the styling of the particles.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please share a working snippet demonstrating your issue.

Comment: We need to see the logic of `particle()` to be able to help you. The timeout is irrelevant to your question

Comment: i guess you want to delete the data in object smoothly

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope its enough for you to see my issue

Answer (score 0):

i would do it with jquery the following way. my way of doing it requires jquery easing plugin. you hve to grap the corresponding DOM-element and do some animation on it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var headline = $("#app-title");

// Do time out here

headline.css({'opacity': 0});
headline.show();
headline.animate({opacity: 1}, {
    step: function (now, mx) {
        headline.css({'opacity': opacity});
    },
    duration: 800,
    complete: function () {

    },
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
});
```